# How to display remote html in an object on IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html

I try to embed a html in an object which failed to display on IE. Here is the js code

```
 document.getElementById('one').innerHTML = '<'+'object id="foo" name="foo" type="text/html" data="'+which.href+'"><\/object>';
```

and here is the html

```
<div id="one"><object id="foo" name="foo" type="text/html" data="$jsurl/animate/right/ap2.html"></object></div>
```

The code displays correctly on other browsers, but not IE, and IFRAME is not an option, cause I need it to be transparent to overlay on top of div.

Need to know how to display it on IE, or any other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the contents of the remote HTML file by using XmlHttpRequest object, then insert the HTML code as innerHTML of your div.

The code could be like this:

```
var request = null;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
     // If IE7, Mozilla, Safari, and so on: Use native object.
      request = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
     // ...otherwise, use the ActiveX control for IE5.x and IE6.
     request = new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
}

request.open('GET', '$jsurl/animate/right/ap2.html', false); 
request.send();

if (request.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById('one').innerHTML = request.responseText;
}
```

Comment: Not quite sure how this should work. I placed your code between <head></head> and place <div id="one"></div> in the body. URL showed correctly for request.open, but nothing showed in the div. Anything I missed?

Comment: Well, the URL of the HTML file ($jsurl/animate/right/ap2.html) seems quite weird, it should rather be something like http://<your server>/animate/right/ap2.html or just /animate/right/ap2.html... What about that $jsurl literal?  Is it a JavaScript variable or something?

Comment: $jsurl is a php variable, which appears correctly as http:// localhost/animate/right/ap2.html (I'm testing on my local machine) when I checked the page source. Btw, I changed the URL to http:// www.google.com. It doesn't load either.

Comment: Just saw what caused the error. An uncaught error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101. Tried loading google.com

Comment: Yes, you cannot load content from another domain using XmlHttpRequest object

Comment: will it not load from same localhost either? That means I have to upload to a server to test this?

Comment: You can test with localhost, asuming you have a local web server (IIS)

Comment: Anyway, I don't how you are getting the $jsurl variable, is it in which.href JavaScript variable?

Comment: Forget about the $jsurl, that's only a defined PHP variable, which I did not use to do the testing. I changed it to http://<ip address>/animate/...  Problem is, there is a NETWORK_ERR.

Comment: If $jsurl is not needed, your original example should work.  I tested it and works (I used www.bing.com as display URL, www.google.com does not allow it to be embedded in object tags): http://jsfiddle.net/YJhs4/

Comment: Yeah, it works for most browsers, just not IE. That's my problem and original post if you notice the title.

Comment: Ok, so the XmlHttpRequest solution will work if you load URLs server from the same domain where page is located (if your test page is served from http://localhost, it should work for loading contents served from http://localhost as well)

Comment: I tested that already, and what I got was uncaught error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101